# Difference between EUID and UID?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

**EUID** is not the same as **UID**. At what context are these both are used in the script?

I tried to get the values by `echo "UID is $UID and EUID is $EUID"`, but only space came as output. My machine runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Seen at some sites that this is usually used to check whether it is root user and all but not able to get proper difference.

Comment: A [link](https://muffinresearch.co.uk/linux-changing-uids-and-gids-for-user/) to know how to change uid and gid. `usermod -u <NEWUID> <LOGIN>    
groupmod -g <NEWGID> <GROUP>  
find / -user <OLDUID> -exec chown -h <NEWUID> {} \;   
find / -group <OLDGID> -exec chgrp -h <NEWGID> {} \;  
usermod -g <NEWGID> <LOGIN>`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

UID is the ID of the user that executed the program.

EUID (Effective UID) is the user ID the process is executing. Usually both are equal, unless using a program with SetUID to for example increase your privileges. A common case where UID and EUID are different would be executing sudo.

EUID and UID variables only work on bash, not in dash (in Debian based distros as Ubuntu sh is usually a symlink to dash).

If you are running the script interactively you might not have bash configured as your default shell, run `bash` before trying.

If you are running it from console:

```
bash script.sh
```

If you are running it using its path (for example `./script.sh`) ensure the first line of the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And not:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

For a more generic way to do it -that works on any shell- check: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15853/how-can-a-script-check-if-its-being-run-as-root

In that post the command `id` is mentioned, where:

```
id -u    # is the EUID
id -u -r # is the UID
```

Comment: which one only works on bash ?? EUID or UID ? you're not clear

Comment: The subject is "Difference between EUID and UID?" but you just tell OP how to get uid or euid or when it works (in bash). Don't know why this is the preferred answer..

Comment: @Matt I wanted to edit the answer of Fernando but the "Suggested edit queue is full".
Both `EUID` and `UID` variables are only available in `bash` and `zsh`

Answer (score 49):

They're different when a program is running set-uid. Effective UID is the user you changed to, UID is the original user.

Comment: So why my current shell not displaying any integer. Could you please explain a little bit more!

Comment: I don't know. It works for me on OS X running bash 3.2.48 and Debian running bash 4.1.5.

Comment: When I am running inside a script it is not coming, but when i write it directly on the shell it is working!

Comment: Works for me both ways.

Comment: OK. May be I should get a guy who runs Ubuntu 12.04 lts to check it!